# Callbacks on two-level doughnut chart in chartjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts

How to implement a proper callback on double-doughnut chart in chartjs?

I know only the way to do something like this:

```
options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
          return data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItems.index] + 'h';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But obviously it isn't working correctly. Because it returns data from first doughnut chart(`data.datasets[0].data`) and returns it for both charts.
How to return data for both charts separately?

Answer (score 2):

Ok it was pretty easy, just use .datasetIndex:

```
label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
          return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItems.index] + 'h';
        }
```